# How to connect and send/receive data to bluetooth device (OBDII) in swift (IOS 8)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, bluetooth

I tried with CoreBluetooth but its impossible. I look for something like BluetoothSocket in Android.

I try ExternalAccessory but my device don't appear, how can I get data from OBDII bluetooth 4.0 (BLE)? Exist another method to connect with device? Also I try CoreBluetooth but don't get data.

Comment: Try to be more specific with your question. What are you trying to archive? Where did you encounter which error?

Comment: BluetoothSocket is for Bluetooth Low-Energy or "Classic Bluetooth" ? If no, then CoreBluetooth is only for Bluetooth Low-Energy, so you'll have to use External-Accessory (with NSInputStream/NSOutputStream) and should be MFi.

Comment: Could you give me an example of use "External-Accesory"?

Comment: So I guess that in fact you don't use Bluetooth Low-Energy ? Look at EADemo from Apple, using ExternalAccessory.framework.

Comment: My device is Viecar 4.0 OBD2 Bluetooth. The example is in obj-c, i don't find information in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple's Bluetooth does not work with the OBDII devices. iOS only supports a limited number of profiles. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387